# JS(JQ) : 'click' срабатывает дважды на втором и более элементах корзины

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Учу JS, есть задание составить корзину без изменения html. Возникает проблема, если в корзине более 1ого элемента, при клике на ('.plus') или ('.minus') элементов выше значение input'a плюсуется и минусуется кратно порядковому номеру. Пробовал вынести эти элементы вне функции ('.btn')-клика, но в этом случае клик не регистрируется на этих кнопках.

Код JS(JQ)

```
$('<div class = "item"></div>').appendTo('.cart') 


$('.btn').on('click', function() {
     $('<button class="plus">+</button>').appendTo('.item')
     $('<button class="minus">-</button>').appendTo('.item')
     $('<input class="stack" value="1" min="1" maxlength="2"></input>').appendTo('.item')

     $('.plus').on('click', function () {
         $(this).next().next()[0].value = ++($(this).next().next()[0].value)
    })

     $('.minus').on('click', function () {
         $(this).next()[0].value = --($(this).next()[0].value)
    })

})
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div>
      <img src="http://www.teleread.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/apple-250x250-logo.jpeg">
    </div>
    <h2>Product Zero</h2>
    <p>Asdfg</p>
    <p>$12.99</p>
    <button class="btn btn-deafult>">Buy</button>
  </div>
```

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: не надо навешивать обработчики внутри обработчика. Вернее не надо навешивать обработчики на все существующие элементы с классом. ?Нужно только на тот, который ты создал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо добавления обработчика каждый раз всем элементам на странице с указанными классами нужно добавлять обработчик только вновь созданным элементам:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    $('<button class="plus">+</button>').on('click', function () { // сначала добавляем обработчик
        $(this).next().next()[0].value = ++($(this).next().next()[0].value)
    }).appendTo('.item') // лишь затем добавляем в `item`, здесь лучше тоже выбрать `item` заранее.
    $('<button class="minus">-</button>').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next()[0].value = --($(this).next()[0].value)
    }).appendTo('.item')
    $('<input class="stack" value="1" min="1" maxlength="2"></input>').appendTo('.item')
});
```